# Database select queries running slow after bulk delete from tables

Tags: sql-server, performance, query-performance

Over the years our sql sever database has accumulated a lot of data which was causing the queries to run slow which further resulted in the application to slow down significantly.

We eventually decided to archive certain data by storing it in a different data store and deleting from SQL Server. Note that the data is spread over 22 tables (meta-data). After deleting about 40% of the data we saw that certain queries were running significantly slower. Even though there are queries which have slight performance improvement, we are observing that the response times and transactions per second have come down significantly when we ran a load test.

As part of cleanup on the database side, we Reorganized and Rebuilt the indexes. We made sure that the fragmentation after the deletes was with in permissible limits (ideally < 30% but it was way less than that). After this we ran update statistics with full scan.

We identified a particular query which runs significantly slower after the deletes and saw that it had a different query plan as compared to before delete (we created a new database with the pre-delete data set to compare the differences) even though the table definitions (indexes, constraints etc) are the same for all tables in the query.

We ran the load tests again after these steps but still saw the same performance as before. I am not a SQL Server expert but am working with closely with the DBAs to understand the underlying issue for the slow down.

The DBAs are suggesting to optimize the queries but I am not convinced if that would actually help, the queries are performing better with a larger dataset which means deleting the data caused some change on the tables which is resulting in the slowdown.

I would really appreciate any pointers or guidance on addressing this issue.

Thanks,

Karthik

Comment: yes we did, we rebuilt, reorganized the indexes followed by Update Statistics with full scan

Comment: When you rebuild all indexes you also get a 'free' update statistics. To answer the question we would have to see the before and after query plans and the query itself.

Comment: There is little anybody can do with such a broad issue. execution plans, table definitions, queries etc.... Without those kinds of details this is just talking in general terms which will not solve your issue.